# How to save the state of my Rstudio workspace

Tags: r, rstudio, rdata

Im working on a large project in Rstudio with code that takes a long time to load.   I was wondering if there was an efficient way that I can save the state of my workspace and variables so that I can easily reopen my workspace when needed with all variables loaded.  I know a little bit about .Rdata files but I was wondering how I can utilize them to do this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rstudio (even R?) automatically saves your latest state into `.Rdata` in your `getwd()` directory.
You may have deactivated this during installation, in which case you can activate it again in `Tools` -> `Global options` -> `General` where you'll see the option under `workspace`.

If this doesn't work you can do this manually using `save.image()` and using `load('.RData')` on startup.